# [Vite build error]Vue 3 typescript with vite build show error default is not exported by <file>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I am building a vue 3 ts project. Running `vite` no problem, when build  `vite build --debug` the project get error.

The error message show like this .

```
error during build:
Error: 'default' is not exported by src\env.d.ts, imported by src\infrastructure\seedwork\imageUrlFormatter.ts
    at error (Projects\vite\vite-user\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:160:30)
```

Method i tried:

1. export default in env.d.ts

```
declare const imageUrlFormatter: any;
export default imageUrlFormatter;
```

Error in env.d.ts gone, but will show in other files like `main.ts`. It will continue to show in next file even after i add the declare above.

Below are the code of my helper code

```
// imageUrlFormatter.ts

function imageUrlFormatter(url: string) {
    return new URL(`/src/${url}`, import.meta.url).href
}

export { imageUrlFormatter }
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ],
            "views/*": [
                "./src/views/*"
            ],
            "seedwork/*": [
                "./src/infrastructure/seedwork/*"
            ],
            "model/*": [
                "./src/infrastructure/model/*"
            ]
        },
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue"
    ]
}
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import path from 'path'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(),
    VitePWA(
        {
            strategies: 'injectManifest',
            registerType: 'autoUpdate',
            includeAssets: ['favicon.svg', 'favicon.ico', 'robots.txt', 'apple-touch-icon.png'],
            manifest: {
                name: 'Name of your app',
                short_name: 'Short name of your app',
                description: 'Description of your app',
                theme_color: '#ffffff',
                icons: [
                    {
                        src: 'pwa-192x192.png',
                        sizes: '192x192',
                        type: 'image/png',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'pwa-512x512.png',
                        sizes: '512x512',
                        type: 'image/png',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'pwa-512x512.png',
                        sizes: '512x512',
                        type: 'image/png',
                        purpose: 'any maskable',
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ), commonjs({
        ignoreDynamicRequires: true
    })],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~/': `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`,
            'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom',
            '@': path.resolve('src'),
            'views': path.resolve('src/views'),
            '@components': path.resolve('src/@components'),
            'seedwork': path.resolve('src/infrastructure/seedwork'),
            'model': path.resolve('src/infrastructure/model'),
            "assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/assets"),
            "~assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/assets")
        }
    },
})
```

I tried search the error above, but couldnt understand what is that mean, anyone that can help and let me know if this error show up how to have a better debug ? Thanks ya.

ps: I have create a smaller project to reproduce my error. Here is the github repo https://github.com/Arios509/vite-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error is due to the `imageUrlFormatter`.

When using vite, it would have the problem when load the image. Hence i created a imageUrlFormatter helper to resolve the path.

After i modify the code for imageUrlFormatter to

```
const imageUrlFormatter = (url: string) => {
    return `src/${url}`;
}
export { imageUrlFormatter }
```

Then it works.

I also updated the `vite.config.ts` for the resolve path like this.

```
...
resolve: {
        alias: {
 ...
            "assets": resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
            "~assets": resolve(__dirname, "/src/assets"),
        }
    },
```

The error hint was never the root cause, wish the `vite build` will give more information about that. Because when normal run `vite` it is just fine not until it needed to build.

Ps: After build success and deploy, this method is not able to cover. I remove this helper and then change to new URL() for each image instead. Anyways, i would still want to see if anyone could help and suggest better solution for using vite build.

Thanks.